# How to get GCM registration ID when I start app at first time after registration GCM?

Tags: registration, google-cloud-messaging

I must get GCM registration ID when I start app at first time after registration GCM.

if I execute app from second time, I can get CGM registration ID(notify id).
but when first time i start, I can't get it...

please tell me how to get?

this is my code:

```
private String GCMConnection() {
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    String notifyId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (notifyId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, GCMParam.SENDER_ID);
        notifyId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    }
    return notifyId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GCMRegistrar.register` is an asynchronous method. If you choose to use it, you can get the response via a broadcast receiver. `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId` returns a non empty value only after the first time your app gets a response to the registration request.

However, that class is deprecated. You are encouraged to use `GoogleCloudMessaging.register` instead, which is synchronous, and therefore shouldn't be run on the main thread.

You can see code samples in the [official GCM guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).